# a multiple choice question on uniformly continuous function

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f :(0, 1) \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Pick out the statements which imply that $f$ is uniformly continuous.
>
> a. $|f (x) − f (y)| ≤ \sqrt{|x − y|}$, for all $x, y ∈ (0, 1) $.
>
> b. $f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \to \frac{1}{2}$ and $f\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right) \to \frac{1}{4}$.
>
> c. $f(x) = x ^{\frac{1}{2}}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)$.

My thoughts:
(c)   is uniformly continuous as limits at $x=0$  and $x=1$ are exists.
(a) and (b) I am not sure.

Comment: Do you know the difference between continuous and uniformly continuous?

Answer (score 1):

(a) Do you *really* know the definition of [uniform continuity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_continuity#Definition_for_functions_on_metric_spaces)? This part is so obvious.

(b) Consider $\left\vert f\left(\frac1{n^2-1}\right)-f\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)\right\vert$. Note that $\left\vert \frac1{n^2-1}-\frac1{n^2}\right\vert$ will be smaller than any prespecified $\delta>0$ when $n$ is large enough.

Comment: Given that $f(1/n^2)$ is a subsequence of $f(1/n)$, I'm tempted to say the contradiction in (b) vacuously implies that $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: @ErickWong Absolutely agree! Yet I think part (b) was intened to mean that $f(1/n)\to1/2$ for the sequence of nonperfect squares.